# I want my Google Script to only send an email when one column is changed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison, logical-operators

Right now, my script successfully sends emails when the status is changed but the problem I am having is that it also sends an email whenever the columns proceeding 15 (in the active row) are changed. I want it to only send emails when column 15 is changed and none else.

My trigger is From Spreadsheet, On edit

```
function sendComplete(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Action Items');
  var r = e.range;
  var actionCol = 15;
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  if (e.value == "Complete" || "In Progress" || "On Hold" || "Awaiting Parts" || "Need Additional Support" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    var row = r.getRowIndex();
    var userEmail = s.getRange(row, 20).getValue();

    var subject = "Status Change for Event #" + s.getRange(row, 1).getValue();

    var body = "Event: " + s.getRange(row, 1).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nCategory:" + s.getRange(row, 4).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nAsset:" + s.getRange(row, 5).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nSub-Section: " + s.getRange(row, 6).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nComponent: " + s.getRange(row, 6).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nProblem: "+ s.getRange(row, 8).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nAction Update: " + s.getRange(row, 9).getValue ();
    body +="\n\nStatus: " + s.getRange(row, 15).getValue ();

    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Review your understanding of logical operator precedence in JavaScript. (I.e. check your `if` statement)

Comment: Not just that, but you can't compare several values with the or operator like that, eg value == foo || bar, it needs to be value == foo || value == bar

Comment: @zack6849 I'd use `Array#indexOf` rather than a bunch of repeated comparisons like that. OP is learning a lot today :)